# Parsing JSON and grouping multiple array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, parsing

I have a JSON response that looks like the following

```
{
  data: [
    {
      attributes:[
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: '10'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [
        {
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '10'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2000',
          stock: '3'
        },
        {
          store_id: '3000',
          stock: '5'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      attributes:[
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: '9'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [
        {
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '10'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2000',
          stock: '3'
        },
        {
          store_id: '4000',
          stock: '5'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      attributes:[
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: '7'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [
        {
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '19'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2001',
          stock: '8'
        },
        {
          store_id: '4000',
          stock: '2'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using JS I'm trying to parse the values and get something that sorts each value via the store ID

e.g

using the data above this is what I would like to achieve

```
array['2000'] = ['10 - (3)', '9 - (3)', '7 - (8)']
```

2000 being the store_id
array values being `size - (stock)`

Comment: No, `array['2000']` should be  `["10 - (3)", "9 - (3)" ]` only. `[7-(8)]` belongs to `array[2001]`. Check my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66979303/9071943) to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to aggregate your data.

Besides, in each `inventory` you should integrate all items to define the value with correct structure like `${attributes[0].value} - (${stock})`

```js
const yourJson = {data:[{attributes:[{type:'size',value:'10'},{type:'colour',value:'red'}],inventory:[{store_id:'1000',stock:'10'},{store_id:'2000',stock:'3'},{store_id:'3000',stock:'5'}]},{attributes:[{type:'size',value:'9'},{type:'colour',value:'red'}],inventory:[{store_id:'1000',stock:'10'},{store_id:'2000',stock:'3'},{store_id:'4000',stock:'5'}]},{attributes:[{type:'size',value:'7'},{type:'colour',value:'red'}],inventory:[{store_id:'1000',stock:'19'},{store_id:'2001',stock:'8'},{store_id:'4000',stock:'2'}]}]};

const result = yourJson.data.reduce((acc, {attributes, inventory}) => 
{
  for(const {store_id, stock} of inventory){
    acc[store_id] = acc[store_id] ||[];
    acc[store_id].push(`${attributes[0].value} - (${stock})`);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) testing it out now. Haven't heard much or looked into array reduce before so I appreciate the support.

Comment: Just tried it in my code, in node js it wont let me do 

            acc[store_id] ??= [];
                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?

Comment: You can change to `acc[store_id] = acc[store_id] ||[];`. I've just updated my answer, pls take a look at

Comment: Is this fine? @cameron-wallace ?

Comment: I appreciate the help :)

just trying to wrap my head around what the code does so I know for the future.

So you reduce the JSON so its easier to map or loop each object in the array?

then the only other bit I dont understand is the 

acc[store_id] = acc[store_id] ||[];

which just sets it as a blank array or the array with items in so it can continue adding to that array?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `reduce()` for that to select the item on the inventory.

Here's an example:

```js
let response = {
  data: [
    {
      attributes:[
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: '10'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [
        {
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '10'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2000',
          stock: '3'
        },
        {
          store_id: '3000',
          stock: '5'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      attributes:[
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: '9'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [
        {
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '10'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2000',
          stock: '3'
        },
        {
          store_id: '4000',
          stock: '5'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      attributes:[
        {
          type: 'size',
          value: '7'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [
        {
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '19'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2001',
          stock: '8'
        },
        {
          store_id: '4000',
          stock: '2'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let selected_inventory = response.data.reduce((a, b) => a = b.inventory.find(inv => inv.store_id === '2000') || a, {})
console.log(selected_inventory) // Expected Result: { "store_id": "2000", "stock": "3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer doesn't seem to give it exactly in the format you want.

```js
function toObj(arr) {
  const obj = {};

  for (const { attributes, inventory } of arr) {
    // Watch out, this assumes there will always be a "size" attribute
    const size = attributes.find(a => a.type === 'size').value;

    for (const inv of inventory) {
      // Assign array if it doesn't exist
      // This will be, for ex, obj['2000']
      obj[inv.store_id] = obj[inv.store_id] || [];

      // Constructs and pushes the final strings
      obj[inv.store_id].push(size + ' - (' + inv.stock + ')');
    }
  }
  
  return obj;
}

const INPUT = {
  data: [{
      attributes: [{
          type: 'size',
          value: '10'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [{
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '10'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2000',
          stock: '3'
        },
        {
          store_id: '3000',
          stock: '5'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      attributes: [{
          type: 'size',
          value: '9'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [{
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '10'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2000',
          stock: '3'
        },
        {
          store_id: '4000',
          stock: '5'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      attributes: [{
          type: 'size',
          value: '7'
        },
        {
          type: 'colour',
          value: 'red'
        }
      ],
      inventory: [{
          store_id: '1000',
          stock: '19'
        },
        {
          store_id: '2001',
          stock: '8'
        },
        {
          store_id: '4000',
          stock: '2'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(toObj(INPUT.data));
```